# Configuring datasource with websphere 8.5.5.0 and Spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, datasource, websphere-8

I was trying to figure it out a problem about connection using websphere 8.5  and spring  . I read some questions about in this site and others but nothing seems to work.

In websphere we HAVE TO set the jndi name of the datasource as jdbc/connection0.

Than I'm trying to set the connection in the web application using the web.xml and the spring configuration files.

```
<resource-ref >
    <description>connection0</description>
    <res-ref-name>connection0</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    <mapped-name>connection0</mapped-name>   
</resource-ref>
```

than in the spring-datasource.xml we try to reference the connection:

```
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/connection0"/>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>           
  </bean>
```

i also added the file ibm-web-bnd.xml to refer to the datasource(the file is under the web-inf directory):

> < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   < web-bnd 
>      xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>      xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee >http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
>      version="1.0" >

we produce an EAR file and we succefully to deploy on the application server.
But when we try to access the database we receive an error this is the stacktrace:

> [05/06/17 9.59.33:514 CEST] 0000006f SystemOut     O it.XXXX.sicurezza.db.DbHelper --> openJndiConnection: Not found initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/url/connection0"). GRAVE!!
>   [05/06/17 9.59.33:515 CEST] 0000006f SystemOut     O 05-06-2017 09:59:33 ERROR [WebContainer : 1] it.XXXX.sicurezza.taglib.allow.AllowTag - NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: java
>   javax.naming.ConfigurationException: NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: java
>     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.checkForUrlContext(Helpers.java:1631)
>     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:160)
>     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
>     at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:423)
>     at it.XXXX.sicurezza.db.DbHelper.openJndiConnection(DbHelper.java:78)
>     at it.XXXX.sicurezza.db.DbHelper.openConnection(DbHelper.java:53)
>     at it.XXXX.sicurezza.db.DaoManager.isInternalSecurityEnabled(DaoManager.java:108)
>     at it.XXXX.sicurezza.manager.AbilitazioniManagerFactory.getAbilitazioniManager(AbilitazioniManagerFactory.java:29)
>     at it.XXXX.sicurezza.taglib.allow.AllowTag.doStartTag(AllowTag.java:116)
>     at com.ibm._jsp._editOrdineForm._jspx_meth_allow_allow_8(_editOrdineForm.java:7626)
>     at com.ibm._jsp._editOrdineForm._jspx_meth_c_if_39(_editOrdineForm.java:7668)
>     at com.ibm._jsp._editOrdineForm._jspService(_editOrdineForm.java:658)
>     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
>     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:549)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:527)
>     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:99)
>     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:135)
>     at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:760)
>     at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:892)
>     at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
>     at com.ibm._jsp._layout._jspx_meth_tiles_insert_3(_layout.java:451)
>     at com.ibm._jsp._layout._jspService(_layout.java:201)
>     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
>     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:240)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:258)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1174)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:240)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:258)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1174)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
>     at it.XXXX.oppe0.allow.filter.AllowFilter.doFilter(AllowFilter.java:125)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
>     at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at it.XXXX.oppe0.acegi.SessionExpirationFilter.doFilter(SessionExpirationFilter.java:76)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
>     at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)

any suggestions for the setup?

Comment: You need to look carefully at this line. `[05/06/17 9.59.33:514 CEST] 0000006f SystemOut O it.infogroup.sicurezza.db.DbHelper --> openJndiConnection: Not found initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/url/connection0"). GRAVE!! ` The path seems to be incorrect as I would expect to see "jdbc/connection0" but instead I sees "url/connection0".

Comment: Please post the code that looks up the datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an application that wants to look up the data source as

```
java:comp/env/url/connection0
```

And your server configuration defines a data source with JNDI name of

```
jdbc/connection0
```

Then your resource reference in web.xml should be

```
<resource-ref >
    <description>connection0</description>
    <res-ref-name>url/connection0</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

and you can define the mapping in the bindings file (ibm-web-bnd.xml) as follows:

```
<resource-ref name="url/connection0" binding-name="jdbc/connection0">
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: Thank you for the  quick reply.however i have a problem in the spring-datasource.xml (it doesn't seem to work like you suggest)

Comment: To clarify, I wasn't suggesting any modifications to spring-datasource.xml, just to the deployment descriptor (web.xml) and bindings (ibm-web-bnd.xml)